# Command "openfiles /local on" on Windows 10 Pro does not work

Tags: windows-10, command-line, system-monitoring

Even after restart, "maintain objects list" stays deactivated. I tried this several times.

After the command

```
openfiles /local on
```

in an administrator command prompt Windows responds something like "the global system thing maintain objects list is activated" (in german), and I should restart.

Comment: If you have the Fast Startup option on in UEFI, then the system might not be performing a full reboot. Try the CMD **shutdown /s /t 0** to force a full reboot, or change the option in UEFI.

Comment: Full success! DrMoishe Pippik is right. The _Fast Startup_ Mode was the culprit. If I had heard of it before, I could have spared my question. 
It would be nice if this was mentioned in the output of `openfiles /local /?` .
 
.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
openfiles /local on
```

either disable *Fast Startup* to make Windows always do a full reboot, or use

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```

to do a full reboot once.